# How to update the form state on input type change

Tags: react-admin

I basically have a record with a `parameters` property that is an array. Each parameter has a `type` and a `value` and the value is dependent on the type. E.g. type `string` means that value can be `"foo"` or `"bar"` while type `bool` means that it has to be `true` or `false`.

This is modeled as a `SelectInput` for the type and a type dependent input for the value (e.g. `BooleanInput`, `TextInput`, ..). The inputs are inside a `FormDataConsumer`, so that the correct value input according to type can be rendered. Something like the following

```js
const renderValueInput = (type, getSource) => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'bool':
        return <BooleanInput source={getSource('value')} label="Value" fullWidth />;
      default:
        return <TextInput source={getSource('value')} label="Value" fullWidth />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <ArrayInput source="parameters">
      <SimpleFormIterator>
        <FormDataConsumer>
          {({ getSource, scopedFormData }) => (
            <>
              <SelectInput
                source={getSource('type')}
                label="Type"
                choices={[
                  { id: 'bool', name: 'Boolean' },
                  { id: 'string', name: 'String' },
                ]}
              />
              { scopedFormData && renderValueInput(scopedFormData.type, getSource) }
            </>
          )}
        </FormDataConsumer>
      </SimpleFormIterator>
    </ArrayInput>
  );
```

So far this is working fine and rendering the correct components, but if the type is changed apparently the form state is not updated for the value. E.g. if the type is changed from bool to string the value stays true or false in the state. But if I change anything in the value input the state is updated again.

I'm now wondering how I can update the form state for value when changing the type? Any ideas? Or is the model / concept that I chose simply wrong?
I'm also not sure if this is a react-final-form or react-admin "problem" tbh.

Comment: I'm starting to think that this is related to https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/issues/891

Comment: fyi I ended up manually updating the form state on type change for now.